# Converting x86-64 code to Y86-64 code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, y86

I am miserably confused right now when trying to discern assembly language.
I am asked to convert the following x86-84 code to Y86-84:

```
long arith(long int x, long int y, long int z) {

return (x+y+z) & (x+4+48*y);

}
```

In x86-64:

```
arith:
leaq (%rsi, %rsi, 2), %rax
salq $4, %rax
leaq 4(%rdi, %rax), %rax
addq %rdi, %rsi
addq %rdx, %rsi
andq %rsi, %rax
ret
```

Before I convert, I'm having a hard time understanding what's even going on in x86-64. I would be immensely appreciative to anyone who could walk me through what is even going on in this code.

Comment: Which part is confusing? Show what you figured out and where you got stuck. See also [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction) and remember that left shift is multiplying by powers of two. First insn gives `3*y`, next `16*3*y`, next the right bracket, next two the left bracket finally the `&`.

Comment: The first two lines were confusing me, but I walked through it more carefully and remembering that the left shift multiplies by powers of two helped a lot. So as I see it now, the first two lines consists of putting 48y into register %rax, the next line consists of placing 48y added by x+4 into %rax, the next 2 lines consist of having the %rsi register contain x+y+z, and the last line does the final & operation of the registers that now have the two desired values.

Comment: With that in mind though, what is important to keep in mind converting to Y86? I was told there is no leaq instruction in y86, so where should I start in trying to  convert?

Comment: Turn them into additions, aren't you overthinking this?

Comment: @Jester : seems like a logical progression of your previous answer dealing with 32-bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545606/ia32-assembly-code-to-y86-assembly-code-leal-instruction

Comment: So to get 48y, I would need to turn leaq into a ton of additions? There's no efficient way of getting 48y into %rax?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first shot:
In Y86:

```
arith:
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rax
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rax
addq %rdi, %rax
addq 4, %rax
addq %rdi, %rsi
addq %rdx, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rax
ret
```

I believe the line 'addq 4, %rax' is incorrect. How should I add 4 to the value stored in the %rax register?

EDIT: I see a bigger issue in that after adding to %rsi I can't seamlessly get x+y+z into %rsi as I did with x86. How can I get x+y+z stored into a register then?

Comment: x86 AT&T syntax would use `add $4`, %rax`, but y86 uses separate mnemonics for loads vs. mov-immediate, doesn't it?  So IDK if it needs to decorate immediates with `$` to distinguish them from memory operands.  But it might require them anyway for consistency.

Comment: The more obvious bug is that you add to `%rax` without moving anything to it first.  On function entry, it holds garbage.  x86 LEA's destination is write-only.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545606/ia32-assembly-code-to-y86-assembly-code-leal-instruction.  I'd suggest `irmov $1, %rax` before the first `add` to RAX, instead of copying a register there.  That saves an instruction vs. copy and then add-immediate.  (I forget if y86 saves code bytes from `irmov $1, %eax` the way x86 does, with implicit zero extension into rax instead of a longer instruction)

Comment: I'm very confused by the irmovq, rmmovq, and mrmovq instructions. What exactly do they accomplish?

Comment: irmov loads a constant into a register. rmmov stores a register to a memory location. mrmov loads a value from memory into a register.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my second shot:

```
arith:
subq %r8, %r8
addq %rdi, %r8
addq %rsi, %r8
addq %rdx, %r8
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rsi
addq %rsi, %rsi
subq %rax, %rax
addq %rsi, %rax
addq %rdi, %rax
addq $4, %rax
andq %r8, %rax
```

Comment: Pretty close. It only multiplies y by 16, so you need another x3 in there. Secondly, there's no add immediate, so you need to put 4 in a register in order to add it.

Comment: Okay, then to do that would I do the following: irmovq 4, %r9; addq %r9, %rax

Comment: And what do you mean another x3? After I add %rsi into %rax, shouldn't I just do another addq %rsi, %rsi, then another addq %rsi, %rax?

Comment: Yes, that's a great way to do it.

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers to your own question.